# setting cell row height without auto layout in xcode 6 in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I am trying to set the row height in xcode 6 but it isn't working.  When I click into a cell and it becomes selected, the height adjusts to what it should be.  However when the table is loaded normally the default height of 44 is used.

Ive set the height of the XIB i am using for the cell in the XIB dimensions, ive set the row height in IB under the 'ruler' tab, and ive tried the 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' delegate, but the height never adjusts.

Comment: Do you reload tableview after adjust cell height?

Comment: yes.  in order to fix this issue in my particular case, i had to adjust the table cell XIB to the default height of 44, then set the height to 60 in heightForRowAtIndexPath.  This got the 'closest' result to what I needed.